# Azure cache control with non-.NET application

Tags: azure, jekyll, cache-control

I'm trying to serve some static content ([Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) if that's relevant) out of an Azure web app. Said web app can also be served out of an Azure CDN. Both urls (CDN and app) work fine.

A chrome audit complains that the assets of my page are missing cache expiration dates. Fair enough.

But uhhh...how do I set cache expiration for an Azure web app or an Azure CDN endpoint?

Can they be set somewhere in the HTML? Can they be set somewhere in the wilds of the Azure console?

Most google answers (including SO) explain how to set the expiration via a `web.config` file, but I don't have one of those, because my application is not a `.NET` app.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question turns out to be dead simple. I just needed to add a web.config file to the root of my jekyll app. Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Coming from a Linux background, I assumed the web.config was a .NET thing, but nope. It sets the IIS (that is, Azure) configuration.